# Scroll to top ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have the following hierarchy: view - scrollView- contentView- tableView and some image.
I want that when tap on a tableCell (image) the contentView to scrollToTop. I know that it's a method scrollViewShouldScrollToTop, but i want the contentView to scroll. Any advice?

Comment: implement delegate method scrollViewShouldScrollToTop and also set scrolView.scrollToTop =YES, but i as said i want the contenteView to scroll

Comment: i made it... one line of code ;)